# Using ASP.NET MVC and jQuery to render partial view/submit a form without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and jQuery, so I thought I'd share how I implemented loading of partial views and submitting forms in a way that doesn't require for the entire page to be refreshed. I hope to get some critique from the experts if there's a better way to do this :)

All the magic is done by 3 javascript functions which I bind to various events, like button click, jQueryUI tab select, etc.

Firstly, this is how I get a partial view:

```
function showAjaxMessage(targetDiv, ajaxMessage) {    
    var ajaxLoader = "<img src='Content/loader.gif' alt=''>";
    $(targetDiv).html("<p>" + ajaxLoader + " " + ajaxMessage+"</p>"); 
}

function getPartialView(actionUrl, targetDiv, ajaxMessage, callback) {
    showAjaxMessage(targetDiv, ajaxMessage);

    $.get(actionUrl, null, function(result) {
        $(targetDiv).html(result);
        callback();
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
getPartialView("MyController/MyAction", "#myDiv", "Loading...", function() { alert('Loaded!'); });
```

This will set whatever the action returned (PartialView) as the content of myDiv and then invoke the callback function (in this case, it will just pop up an alert) with a nice  "Loading..." message displayed in the div while we wait for the response.

Secondly, submitting a form:

```
function submitForm(actionUrl, targetDiv, ajaxMessage, form, callback) {

    var data = $(form).serialize();
    showAjaxMessage(targetDiv, ajaxMessage);
    $.post(
        actionUrl,
        data,
        function(data) {
            $(targetDiv).html(data);
            callback();
        }
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
submitForm("MyController/MyAction", "#myDiv", "Submitting...", "#myForm", function() { alert('Submitted!'); });
```

Once again, this invokes a controller action, but this time it does a POST with the given form's data (<form id="myForm">) serialized as "input1=value1&input2=value2&...&inputn=valuen", allowing the action to do something with the user input, like so:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
{
    // eg. TryUpdateModel<MyActionViewModel>(this.myActionViewModel);
    // or 
    // do something with form["input1"] ...

    return PartialView("MyPartialView", this.myActionViewModel);
}
```

The HTML returned is once again rendered into myDiv and a callback function is invoked.

I haven't added any validation as yet, but the basics work quite nicely, but if there is a better way, please share :)

Comment: This looks more like a blog post than a question to me.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer - it's a bit of both, I'm interested to know if I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use [jQuery.taconite](http://malsup.com/jquery/taconite/):

- it's more flexible, allowing multiple DOM updates in one request.
- It's [extensible](http://malsup.com/jquery/taconite/#extend).
- It's [thoroughly tested](http://malsup.com/jquery/taconite/test/).